# How to create a view slider containing user list?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I want to create view slider in Drupal 7. Can this be possible? The view slider must contain an image of the user and user name in the site.

[click here to see view slider image](http://indocosmo.in/newartcheck/view%20slider.JPG)

Answer (score 0):

For what you have described, I would suggest using [jCarousel](http://drupal.org/project/jcarousel) or [Views Slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow).  You can theme both of them to your liking.